# Manipulating user input (Mathematical)

Tags: c#

I'm using C#. I am trying to allow the user to input a numerical value (IE: how many do you want?) and then take that value and figure tax and total. I can not figure out how to do this and wondered if anyone could show me? My current script is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Infinate Happiness Ranch.\nPlease enter your order information bellow. ");

            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your first and last name:");
            string FirstName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your street address:");
            string Address = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your city:");
            string City = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your two letter state abbreviation:");
            string StateCode = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your zip code:");
            string ZipCode = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of Tribbles \nyou wish to purchase for $29.99 plus tax");
            string NumberOrdered = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Invoice \nName {0}", FirstName);
            Console.WriteLine("Address {0}", Address);
            Console.WriteLine("City {0}", City);
            Console.WriteLine("StateCode {0}", StateCode);
            Console.WriteLine("ZipCode {0}", ZipCode);
            Console.WriteLine("NumberOrdered {0}", NumberOrdered);
            // PROGRAM WORKS UNTIL HERE.
            NumberOrdered = m;
            TotalBeforeTax = m * 29.99; //'n' is total b4 tax
            o = n * 0.9;// 'o' is total tax due
            p = o + n; // 'p' is total due

            Console.WriteLine("Your total is {0} {1}", n);
            Console.WriteLine("Your tax is {0}", o);
            Console.WriteLine("Your total charge is {0}", p);
            Console.WriteLine("Thank you for your order");
            Console.WriteLine();

            //Console.WriteLine("Name:" + FirstName);
            Console.Read();    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your program does not compile. Don't ever say that your program "doesn't work". Explain what you expect to happen, and what actually happens.

Comment: What is `m`?  I don't see where it's defined.

Comment: That's a pretty long program. Maybe you can remove all unnecessary things like `using`s etc.?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to do math with `string`s.  They don't like that.  Convert them to `int`, `float` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You should parse the string with

```
int ordered = int.Parse(NumberOrdered);
```

And continue to calculate with this integer.

Answer (score 0):

Because the user is entering information as strings, you should convert the number ordered to an integer. Also, to preserve your decimals, you need to store numbers as doubles for things such amounts.

```
int numOrdered = Convert.ToInt32(NumberOrdered);
double TotalBeforeTax = numOrdered * 29.99; 

double beforeTax = TotalBeforeTax * 0.9;
double afterTax = beforeTax + TotalBeforeTax;

Console.WriteLine("Your total is {0}", TotalBeforeTax);
Console.WriteLine("Your tax is {0}", beforeTax);
Console.WriteLine("Your total charge is {0}", afterTax);
Console.WriteLine("Thank you for your order");
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to declare some variables and assign some values​​.

Try this:

```
static float m;
static float n;
static float o;
static float p;
static float TotalBeforeTax;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to  Infinate Happiness Ranch.\nPlease enter your order information bellow. ");
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your first and last name:");
    string FirstName = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your street address:");
    string Address = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your city:");
    string City = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your two letter state abreviation:");
    string StateCode = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your zip code:");
    string ZipCode = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of Tribbles \nyou wish to purchase for $29.99 plus tax");
    string NumberOrdered = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Invoice \nName {0}", FirstName);
    Console.WriteLine("Address {0}", Address);
    Console.WriteLine("City {0}", City);
    Console.WriteLine("StateCode {0}", StateCode);
    Console.WriteLine("ZipCode {0}", ZipCode);
    Console.WriteLine("NumberOrdered {0}", NumberOrdered);
    //PROGRAM WORKS UNTIL HERE ? HELP ? ? ? ? ?
    //NumberOrdered = m;
    m = float.Parse(NumberOrdered);
    TotalBeforeTax = m * 29.99f; //'n' is total b4 tax
    n = TotalBeforeTax;
    o = n * 0.9f;//'o' is total tax due
    p = o + n; //'p' is total due

    Console.WriteLine("Your total is {0}", n);
    Console.WriteLine("Your tax is {0}", o);
    Console.WriteLine("Your total charge is {0}", p);
    Console.WriteLine("Thank you for your order");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Read();
}
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score -3):

Just a bit of advice, you can include non-string variables in Console.WriteLine() like:

```
Console.WriteLine("Your tax is " + o);
```

This is what most professional developers do. No need for complicated C/C++ style of parsing.

Also, you don't seem to be declaring the variables o and p. Try this:

double o = Convert.toDouble(n * 0.9);

or

double o = (double)(n * 0.9);

Comment: That's a pretty big generalization... There is no reason to steer people away from the string format approach.

Comment: There's plenty. It's a more intuitive way of coding, making it easier to understand and reducing the likelihood of human error, especially when dealing with multiple variables of different types.

Comment: Bad advice. Doesn't answer the question.